# Angularjs + webforms results in Viewstate mac exceptions

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, webforms, sitecore

We're using Angular1 and Sitecore + WebForms together, but in some forms a `System.Web.UI.ViewStateException` error occurs.
It says MAC validation failed, though we have our Machinekey, etc set up correctly.
I was wondering if the errors have anything to do with the JavaScript that WebForms injects, not being picked up by Angular.

The error only appears sometimes, so it might be a race condition.

Is it because WebForms js and Angular don't integrate?
How could we bridge this gap?

Comment: Just want to clarify, when you say "WebForms", are you referring to WebForms, the framework (the alternative to MVC) or are you referring to the Webforms For Marketers module?

Comment: I am talking about asp.net WebForms

Comment: Also, I'm asking the question in SO instead of Sitecore because I believe it is more related to WebForms than to Sitecore.